# Converting hours to minutes in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

Is there a way to convert hours to minutes in xslt?

Source XML:       `<hours>1:30</hours>`

expected is like: `<minutes>90</minutes>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following XPath expression should do the trick:

```
substring-before(hours, ':') * 60 + substring-after(hours, ':')
```